# License plates have 3 digits followed by 3 letters or 3 letters followed by 3 digits. How many are possible? How many had a repeating letter or digit?

Tags: combinatorics

My book gives the answer as

$$26^{3} * 2000 $$ for the first part and

$$26^{3} * 2000 - (26 * 25 * 24) * (10 * 9 * 8) * 2 $$

for the second part.

Shouldn't it be $26^{3} * 1000$, or $26^{3} * 10^{3}$ for the first and second part?

I am also confused why we multiply by 2 in the second part. I understand we're subtracting all the license plates that don't repeat from all license plates, but why do we have to multiply this by 2?

Answer (score 3):

The extra factor of $2$ appears because of the fact that we may choose to have $3$ digits followed by $3$ letters **OR** $3$ letters followed by $3$ digits.  Without the extra factor of $2$, you would be considering only those license plates which begin with digits and end with letters only.